# Report Builder 3.0 - Help to remove blank rows in text file export

Tags: reporting-services

Built a report to export into a text file and unable to find the trick to remove the blank rows. Lines have to one right after another as our Accounting system requires.

Need this:
XXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXX

Getting this:

XXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXX

XXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXX

I have tried hiding them to no avail. Also, the report did have to have the headings removed due to they wanted to print to my text file. 
Ideas would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Did you set the Top and Bottom padding in the cells to 0?

Comment: Yes and the tables are sitting in line with the left of the page and right under one another at 0. This one has me stuck..